# Can't get 12.04 to install

Tags: 12.04, installation, asus

Trying to load Ubuntu 12.04 on an ASUS F5 laptop (PRO50G - Pentium t3200). The install CD has already been used to install 12.04 on another laptop.

Ubuntu appears to be loading until it gets to the Welcome screen that I understand should have the language selection on it. Whatever it should have is blank and all options (menu bars) are unresponsive. All I am able to do is a forced power down.

As a relatively new person to Linux, I am unfamiliar with any way to get control of the laptop. This is the first time I have had a problem installing Ubuntu.

I also tried using the 11.10 and 10.04 install discs with same result.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the "alternate" install CD. It is a text only interface, but it does cope with some more hardware variations.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the graphics on new laptops may work perfectly with the default Ubuntu configuration (they will work fine once you install the drivers after you have installed Ubuntu itself). Try the alternate CD as recommended first.
[Alternate 12.04 32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso) / [Alternate 12.04 64bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso)

There may be some problems with your CD drive or with the CD itself.
Try to create a USB bootable stick as described here [Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) - [Mac](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) - [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
from the alternate install ISO.

Boot from USB and tell us if it worked!

If the install still fails, re-download your Ubuntu ISO and re-burn or re-create usb stick. You may have a broken file.

If none worked, try to install it from Windows using Wubi, as described [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)

Comment: `You may have a broken file` The OP has already used this disc to install another system. Do you mean physical CD damage?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same issue as with the Asus U46. Try the first solution in:
http://lduros.net/posts/gnu-linux-booting-asus-u46/

It requires to turn off VT-d in the bios.